# Must the person who requests an SSL certificate have their private key on their machine?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509, csr

I am trying to create on the server side certificates for my website users so they could authenticate themselves, instead of the basic authentication I already offer which is username/password.

Can I do the whole process of generating the public/private keys for creating the CSR, on the server side instead of on the client side?

I was thinking of the following process:

The user logs into the website and authenticate themselves by username/password.

The user will submit identifying details through a web form over SSL connection between the user browser and the server.

Then the server will create the public/private keys for that user, and use these to create the CSR on the server. Then the server will use the CSR to create the certificate for the user. Then it will send the certificate to the user over SSL. Then the server will erase the created public/private keys.

Finally, the user will install the certificate on their browser.

Is this going to work? Is it unsafe in some way?
Is it okay to move like that from the client side to the server side the responsibility of creating the public/private keys for creating the CSR?
Will this make the created certificate less useful in some way for the user?

Comment: [Startcom](https://cert.startcom.org/) uses this workflow. First you create an account with a username/password. Once the basic account is created, they issue you a PKI certificate to access all services. You should study their workflow.

Comment: I saw the following post earlier today http://security.stackexchange.com/a/22682/46055 but was wondering, is the user's private key used for signing the CSR, required for anything other than the procedure of issuing the certificate? If not, why are people in the linked discussion concerned about Startcom (possibly) saving those private keys?

Comment: "... is the user's private key used for signing the CSR..." - no, the CSR is not signed by the subject (i.e., user). The only thing that CA needs is the subject's info (i.e., the user's info) and his/her public key. That's all a X509 certificate does - its binds a public key to an entity. The binding occurs through the tursted party's signature (i.e., the CA's signature).

Comment: "... why are people in the linked discussion concerned about Startcom (possibly) saving those private keys" - Startcom does that to make it easy on some users (think: the non-techie people). The SE observations are correct - you should not allow folks like Startcom to generate the private key (by the way, Microsoft does the same thing in its developer program). Since you are a technical user, you should just use an alternate method (i.e., do the extra work to keep things secure).

Comment: @jww I cannot see your reply why people are concerned. What is not going to work if they don't have their private key on their machine, or if somebody else has their private key?

Comment: what happens in Startcom's flow is (I believe): either Startcom or the browser generates the private key and creates the certificate. Then, the key and cert are installed in the keystore. That's why Startcom has browser requirements - the browser needs access to the store. [Firefox on Mac OS X does not work](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=963354) because Firefox cannot access the Keychain. If you don't automate things, then it won't be used. PKI and Client Certificates are a perfect example. Add the user, and they avoid it because its too difficult to use.

Comment: but you are right - the user usually needs to access their key. The tricky part is creating the system that's easy to use for the user. If its not easy to use, then the user won't use it (they will expend effort trying to avoid it). Like I (and others) have said: that's why PKI, Client Certificates and Browsers have failed in practice. Its not easy to use.

Comment: Ok, so you say the client must have also their private key installed on their system for the cert to work.. at what point of the handshake or encrypted communication is the private key of the client being used? Also, since you said client certificate failed in practice, what technologies are considered as alternatives to client certificate?

Comment: To correct an error above, "no, the CSR is not signed by the subject (i.e., user). The only thing that CA needs is the subject's info (i.e., the user's info) and his/her public key" is all wrong. The CSR is indeed signed by the user's private key, and that is how the CA knows that the public key in the CSR belongs to the user and not to somebody else. The CA needs this digital signature. @jww

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the person who requests an SSL certificate must have their private key on their machine?

Yes. The client cannot present the certificate as their own in the SSL handshake without the private key, as a digital signature with that key is also part of the SSL handshake, to verify that the client owns it. If the client didn't need the private key to present the certificate, anybody could present anybody's certificate and the whole system would be completely pointless.

> Is this going to work?

No.

> Is it unsafe in some way?

Yes.

> Is it okay to move like that from the client side to the server side the responsibility of creating the public/private keys for creating the CSR?

No.

> Will this make the created certificate less useful in some way for the user?

Yes.

It isn't going to work. You have to find a secure way for the private key to exist on the client machine.

What you're proposing is completely and utterly invalid and insecure. The private key is supposed to be private to the person that owns it. If anybody else knows it, it cannot perform the function for which it is designed. Specifically, anybody who has it can impersonate the owner. People who design workflows like this are letting themselves in for a world of legal pain. Have a think about loss of non-repudiation for a start.

Comment: Well, since the creation of the keys, CSR, and certificate, are all done on the server side, it's done according to the requirements (if our purpose were to create a self-signed certificate for the server). The server can now send the certificate to the applicant. The server just needs to know that the applicant is the true person they claimed to be on the request form. This is done by authenticating by username/password the applicant before they submit the request form. I don't see any flaw in this workflow. Also, from your description it seems like the private key is no longer used later.

Comment: The requirement for a private key is that it's private. If you have it on the server as well as the client, it isn't private. I have already explicitly addressed your final sentence: "The client cannot present the certificate as their own in the SSL handshake without the private key". The flaws in this workflow are: (1) that the private key isn't private or alternatively (2) a certificate without a private key isn't any use, and (3) you lose non-repudiability of client transactions. This isn't a minor matter and you should take legal advice about it.

Comment: Thank you. However here are my thoughts: (1) the private key requirement in the cert creation algorithm has a purpose... to create a signature, so that the CA could authenticate the applicant. That purpose is still fulfilled. (2) why? the applicant can serve the cert to authenticate themselves. That's a use. (3) by this you mean??? that the encryption  can be violated? the private key used for signing CSR is not used after the certificate was sent to applicant. Or you mean that CA might share it with other? so what? authentication was done already. And the premise is that CA is trusted.

Comment: For the third time, the client needs the private key to execute the SSL handshake. 'The private key requirement in the cert creation algorithm' puts the cart before the horse. The only purpose of the *certificate* is to authenticate the public key, whose only purpose in turn is to be used in conjunction with the private key, e.g. in an SSL handshake. And I repeat again that if you have the private key, you can impersonate the applicant, and he can therefore shift all responsibility for any transactions he executes back to you. Legally. Non-repudiation is lost. Look it up. Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: At what point in the handshake, does the client use their private key?

Comment: @rapt In the CertificateVerify message. See RFC 2246.